# How to configure a Spring bean via an in-place annotation?

Tags: java, spring

Let there is a proptotype-scope bean injected:

```
@Autowire
@CustomConfig(foo=100, bar="bar")
MyBean myBean;
```

I wish this would finally lead to initialization steps like:

```
myBean = new MyBean();
myBean.setFoo(100);
myBean.setBar("bar");
// let some standard configuration to be applied here
```

Is it possible to do in such way? Without separate xml/java configuration...

I don't want to avoid standard xml/java configuration completely, but I'd like to use such setup *in addition* to them. Spring 4.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, why not simply set those properties in an `@PostConstruct` method. They seem static in the annotation, so just add a `@PostConstruct` method to set those properties. You can of course always create a custom `BeanPostProcessor` which checks the annotation, and does it thing, but I guess it would be easier to do it in a `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: Thanks! Custom `BeanPostProcessor` looks interesting but I found it gives us a poor interface - a bean and its name - there is no field/method to obtain my annotation from. Maybe there is an adavanced post processor? The `@PostConstruct` way obliges me to write setup code in *each* class which uses my bean, which is too complex for the task - I'd like to register a single processor per application. Maybe AspectJ can do the trick...

Comment: Ofcourse it only gives you the bean and the name. You need to scan the bean for the annotation yourself (that is also how `@autowired` for instance works).